# Best way to get c-stlye callback event to a qt5 signal

Tags: c++, qt5

In my Qt5 project, I am interacting with a piece of hardware through a C-Style library that provides me with event updates through a C-Style callback method. The callback runs on the library thread for which I'd like to return control immediately. My goal is to forward a signal when the hardware library provides me with an event update. I have found a solution shown below but I am not sure if it's the best way. Is there a better method? Would using Qt::postEvent() work better within my registerd callback instead? What would that look like?

```
// hw_api.h
// C-Style library
class HWLIB {
public:
    static HWLIB& GetInstance();
    
    void (*_update1CB)(uint8_t, uint8_t);
    void (*_update2CB)(double, double);
    void (*_update3CB)(uint8_t, uint8_t);

    void SetUpdate1CB(void (cbFunc)(uint8_t old_value, uint8_t new_value)) {
        _update1CB = cbFunc;
    }
    void SetUpdate2CB(void (cbFunc)(double old_value, double new_value)) {...}
    void SetUpdate3CB(void (cbFunc)(uint8_t old_value, uint8_t new_value)) {...}
private:
    HWLIB();
};
```

```
// hw_api_interface.h
class hwi : public QObject {
    Q_Object
signals:
    // Receiver must use Qt::QueuedConnection
    void status1Changed(bool);
    void status2Changed(double);
    void status3Changed(bool);
private:
    HWLILB m_lib;

    static std::function<void(const bool &)> update1Delegate;
    static std::function<void(const double &)> update2Delegate;
    static std::function<void(const bool &)> update3Delegate;

    // Static methods to use in c-style callback but doesn't have access to class signals and member variables
    static void update1CB(uint8_t, uint8_t);
    static void update2CB(double, double);
    static void update2CB(uint8_t, uint8_t);

};
```

```
// hw_api_interface.cpp
// Use static functions to call class member variables to have access to signals
std::function<void(const bool &)> hwi::update1Delegate{};
std::function<void(const double &)> hwi::update2Delegate{};
std::function<void(const bool &)> hwi::update3Delegate{};

hwi::hwi() : m_lib(HWLIB::GetInstance())
{
    update1Delegate = [&](auto value) { emit status1Changed(value); };
    update2Delegate = [&](auto value) { emit status2Changed(value); };
    update3Delegate = [&](auto value) { emit status3Changed(value); };

    // Register call backs
    m_lib.SetUpdate1CB(update1CB);
    m_lib.SetUpdate2CB(update2CB);
    m_lib.SetUpdate3CB(update3CB);
}

void hwi::update1CB(uint8_t old_value, uint8_t new_value)
{
    update1Delegate(static_cast<bool>(new_value));
}

void hwi::update2CB(double old_value, double new_value)
{
    update2Delegate(new_value);
}

void hwi::update3CB(uint8_t old_value, uint8_t new_value)
{
    update3Delegate(static_cast<bool>(new_value));
}

// void hwi::update3CB(uint8_t old_value, uint8_t new_value)
// {
//     Qt::postEvent(update1Changed, new_value); // new_value wrapped in QEvent?
// }
```

Comment: A Queued Qt-signal or a call to `postEvent()` will both work equally well (if you look in the Qt source code, you'll notice that `emit`-ing a Queued Qt-signal is implemented internally by a call to `postEvent()` anyway), so use whichever one you like better.

Comment: Is there a nifty template I could use for the static methods? I tried using option 6 from [here](https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/languages/c-plus-plus/callbacks/) but I am not sure how to have multiple callbacks with this design.